Can't remove dynamic-body component from entity
AFRAME.registerComponent('collision-handler', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    var sceneEl = document.getElementsByTagName('a-scene');
    var fruit = document.getElementById("#fruit");
    el.addEventListener('collide', function collision (event) {
      var collidedEntity = event.detail.body.el;
        if (collidedEntity.id === '#fruit') {
          fruit.removeAttribute('body-merger: dynamic-body');
          fruit.removeAttribute('dynamic-body');
          // fruit.removeAttribute('scale');
          el.removeEventListener('collide', collision);
          console.log('Collided with entity with ID "#fruit"');
        }
    });
    // fruit.removeAttribute('dynamic-body');
    // fruit.removeAttribute('body-merger: dynamic-body');
  }
});

the error can be recreated by using a superhands entity to grab the #knife entity and colliding it with the fruit entity and im very confused as to how this component is crashing; the error in question is TypeError: _bi2 is undefined. (i cant find what this means)
as you can see in the commented lines above, ive tried debugging a little and it seems that the error only appears when i try to remove dynamic body and body merger while they are inside of the event listener.
does anybody have an explanation?
entities related to the component:
<a-entity id="#fruit" position="1.5 2 -2" dynamic-body mixin="interactable" body-merger="dynamic-body" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5">
  <a-box mixin="cube" dynamic-body position="0 0 0" color="blue"></a-box>
  <a-box mixin="cube" dynamic-body position="-0.5 0 0" color="red"></a-box>
  <a-box mixin="cube" dynamic-body position="0.5 0 0" color="green"></a-box>
</a-entity>
<a-box id="#knife" position="0.5 2 -2" static-body mixin="interactable" geometry="width: 0.25; height: 0.25; depth: 1" color="purple" collision-handler></a-box>

related packages:
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/c-frame/aframe-physics-system@v4.1.0/dist/aframe-physics-system.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/c-frame/aframe-extras@7.2.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-physics-extras/dist/aframe-physics-extras.min.js"></script>

glitch link

collidedEntity.id === '#fruit' isnt in the same scope as 'var fruit = document.getElementById("#fruit");'  think you're using scope and selectors wrong?

i enter successfully into the if statement, the problem residse inside the statement

TypeError: _bi2 is undefined - means that there is a undefined object. It's really not clear based on the code youve posted what that might be... if you could point out what line the error is thrown from it would help
